# How to calculate the average from two variables?

Tags: r

I am a beginner of R language, I have a problem now, if you can help me, I will be very grateful.
I now have three columns of data, name, amount of money, and type, and I need to average the amount of money for the same person by type. In detail, for person A, the same type of money is averaged. I attach a picture to illustrate my problem.

[and the left is what I had, the right is what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEcld.png) Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: as a beginner you will benefit from the following book, and in particular chapter 5; https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html